# Is there a difference between piezo electric actuator and piezo actuator?

Tags: terminology, piezoelectric

I read concepts of both the **piezoelectric actuator** and **piezo actuator** in scientific articles.

Are the notions totally same? or is there a difference between a piezoelectric actuator and piezo actuator?

I wonder the photos/videos of actuators from real world about how to use for bridge, train bridges etc.?  But I can' t find on the internet. There are generally writings, or charts on the internet not real photos

Comment: I suppose there's nothing preventing someone from having a pawl made of quartz in some machine and refering to it as a "piezo actuator", but in most of the real world "piezo" is simply short for "piezoelectric".  Nerds tend to prefer such abbreviations.

Comment: An image search on "piezo tubes" will show you photos and diagrams of tubular piezoelectric actuators. But those are still used for small-amplitude motions, not for opening bridges.  For larger displacements, there are piezoelectric inchworms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure that any use of the word "*piezo*" is shorthand for "*piezoelectric*".

- **An actuator** is a [motion-inducing mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actuator), usually as a part of a mechanical dynamic structure as you give some example of in the quesiton.
- **A piezo actuator** or **piezo electric actuator** is that same thing based on the piezoelectric effect, meaning crystals that for a set voltage tend to shrink or expand.

When the term *piezo actuators* is used, it seems to be no different and just another term for that same thing, for example as found in many product descriptions i.e. [here](http://www.madcitylabs.com/piezoactuators.html?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI7dy7nYbE2QIVC5SyCh2DkwvZEAAYBCAAEgIUVfD_BwE) and [here](https://www.ceramtec.com/applications/piezo-applications/actuator-technology/with-active-moisture-suppression/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI7dy7nYbE2QIVC5SyCh2DkwvZEAAYAiAAEgKM9PD_BwE).